# Filter FileSystemWatcher changed events

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I'm writing C# and using to FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory of folders (folders can be Created and Renamed).  I'm successfully processing the Created and Renamed events.

The contents of these folders can constantly change.  But the ONLY change that I need to be cognizant of is when a new HTML file is added to the folder.

How do I filter out all Change Events except for the new [HTML] file?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a wildcard in the constructor for the type of files to watch for:

```
var folder = @"c:\";    
FileSystemWatcher watcher = newFileSystemWatcher(folder, "*.html");
```

Then, if you only want to be notified when those files are created:

```
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_FileCreated);

void watcher_FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
// do something interesting
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I'm 'watching' a directory where Folders can be Created and Renamed. It's the contents of the folders that can change (i.e. adding another HTML file).  My change event handler is catching EVERY change that is happening in the folder.  I just want to catch the new [html] file.

Comment: Are you specifying a filter in the constructor (*.html in my example above)? If so, it should only be firing when a change happens that matches the wildcard.

Comment: If I use *.html as my filter, would I still be able to catch the  Create and Renamed events? Below is my code:

Comment: FileSystemWatcher endoFileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(); endoFileWatcher.Path = listenDir; endoFileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(createEventListener ); endoFileWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler( renamedEventListener ); endoFileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler( changedEventHandler ); endoFileWatcher.Filter = "*"; endoFileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

Comment: @llg:  Please edit your question with the code.  Comments are not the place for code samples.

Answer (score 0):

`FileSystemEventArgs` contains a property called `Name` that will help you filter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventargs.aspx

Quick sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = @"C:\";
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler((o,s) => {
        if (s.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".html") || s.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".htm"))
             Console.WriteLine("HTML is here");
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Note that you could pass in "*.html" to the constructor, but you would not be capturing files ending in .htm files, which are considered valid.  But I'm not sure if that meets your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Just subscribe to the Change event and filter appropriately with your existing FSW.  If you can create another FSW, then Paul Kearney's answer will be sufficient and likely much cleaner.

```
string[] desiredExtensions = new [] { ".html", ... };
string desiredExtension = ".html";


watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;

...

private void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   // single
   if (string.Equals(Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath), desiredExtension, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
   { ... }

   // several
   if (desiredExtensions.Any(ext => string.Equals(Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath), ext, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
   { ... }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, two FSW's, one for the Created and Renamed event and another for the new HTML file change event.  THANK YOU!